# Java Spring send 422 in response when input Id is string

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have a Rest controller and in my controller I have  method for showing single user record. consider url is like this :

```
/api/v1/users/{id}
```

and this is my method

```java
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    @Operation(summary = "Show single user", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth"))
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Found the User", content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = UserDto.class)) }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "User not found", content = @Content)
    })
    public UserDto getUserById(@PathVariable Long id) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        return modelMapper.map(userService.findUserById(id), UserDto.class);
    }
```

The problem is when I send "/api/v1/users/some-string" then I get 500, how can I handle this and return 422 with message of invalid user id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare `@ExceptionHandler` method for `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` in your controller or in separate class annotated `@ControllerAdvice` or `@RestControllerAdvice`, for example so:

```
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
    ApiError handleMethodArgumentTypeMismatchException(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException e) {
        // construct ApiError
        // return ApiError
    }
```